# How to sort alphabet in TreeMap by descending Value in Java

Tags: java

Let's say that I have a TreeMap Alphabet in Java:

`Map<String, Integer> alphabet = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();`

and we put the letter as a key and its number as a value in the map without sorting them at all:

```
alphabet.put("a", 1);
alphabet.put("c", 3);
alphabet.put("b", 2);
alphabet.put("u", 21);
alphabet.put("l", 12);
.
.
.
alphabet.put("y", 25);
alphabet.put("z", 26);
```

And I want to order them by descending value (from 26 to 1). I want to print something like this:

```
z   26
y   25
x   24
.
.
.
d   4
c   3
b   2
a   1
```

Could not find anything simple enough without overcomplicating the code for this specific example.

I will use this for just understanding the logic behind sorting Maps, so I can continue solving another task for homework.
Thanks

Comment: Unless you do it just for training, ordering by value is a bad idea though ordering in sorted map is designed to be based on keys, not values

Comment: `TreeMap` is sorted based on its keys, not its values, so it doesn't help you here. If you're using Java 8, there's an easy way to sort a map by its values. It's one of the answers in the linked duplicate, and here's how it's used for your example: https://ideone.com/7EAJPE